# how to check if a dialogExtended Div is in minimise position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have an extended div like this :

```
var $chatTemplateDiv = $('#ChatTemplate');
 var dialogExtendOptions = {
     "close": true,
     "maximize": false,
     "minimize": true,
     "dblclick": 'minimize',
     "titlebar": 'transparent',
     "restore": function (event, ui) {

     }
 };
 $chatTemplateDiv.dialog({
         title: ClientName,
         width: 360,
         height: 320,
         modal: false,
         resizable: false,
         maxHeight: 500,
         focus: function (event, ui) {
             $("#ToClientID").val(ToClient); 

         },
         open: function (event, ui) {

             $(this).animate({
                 scrollTop: $(this).scrollTop() + 10000000
             });

         }
     }).dialogExtend(dialogExtendOptions);
```

How can i know if a user minimised the div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using this plugin https://code.google.com/p/jquery-dialogextend/    then you can do that like this:

it contains two events `beforeMinimize` & `minimize` so try one of them whatever suits you.

```
 var dialogExtendOptions = {
     "close": true,
     "maximize": false,
     "minimize": true,
     "dblclick": 'minimize',
     "titlebar": 'transparent',
     "restore": function (event, ui) {

     },"events" : {
          "beforeMinimize" : function(evt, dlg){ alert(evt.type+"."+evt.handleObj.namespace); },
          "minimize" : function(evt, dlg){ alert(evt.type+"."+evt.handleObj.namespace); }
        }
 };
```

Then write rest of your code as you written above in your question.

**EDIT**

Ok as you are saying that you want to identify that it is minimized or not. So you can do that like this:

As explained in official documentation:

```
switch ( $("#my-dialog").dialogExtend("state") ) {
  case "maximized":
    alert("The dialog is maximized");
    break;
  case "minimized":
    alert("The dialog is minimized");
    break;
  case "collapsed":
    alert("The dialog is collapsed");
    break;
  default:
    alert("The dialog is normal");
}
```

Use this whenever you want to identify that is it minimized or not.

So if you want to identify that your dialog minimized or not on a button click so you can do that like this:

```
$("#yourbutton").on('click',function(){
switch ( $('#ChatTemplate').dialogExtend("state") ) {
  case "minimized":
    alert("The dialog is minimized");
    }

});
```

Comment: i want to check if the div is currently minimised how can i do this

Comment: yeah i check the plugin link and i discovered that haha thank u :)